# How can I use other hotkey instead of Ctrl+C in Xshell？

Tags: xshell

I use xshell in win10. The hot key Ctrl+C in win10 is copy and in xshell is stop(or may be kill the process.) I want to use Ctrl+C to copy sth and map other hotkey like Ctrl+W instead. Now all I find is using other hotkey to copy. If I remapping the Ctrl+C to copy, how could I stop the current process? I tried [toos]->[Options]->[Keyboard and Mouse]. In [Custom Key mapping] which function could instead of Ctrl+C? I have tried [Edit] Send break, [Edit] Sun key-Stop and [Tools] Cancel Script, but none of them works. So how can I use other hot key instead of Ctrl+C? Thanks.